# Using the value from a prop to determine what to show

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show a required textfield if reasonId = 2 otherwise TextField should not be required if reasonId is
any other number. How can I write this using an if statement or any shorter way?

```
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-xs-12'>
              {props.selectedReason.reasonId === 2 &&
                <TextField
                  required
                  multiline
                  className='text-area'
                  fullWidth
                  value={props.selectedReason.reason}
                  onChange={event => {
                    props.handleChangeReason({
                      ...props.selectedReason,
                      reason: event.target.value
                    });
                  }}
                />
              }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's the way react documentation suggests, i think there is no reason to change

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There has to be a way to write this using an if statement.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html read this doc here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set required field conditionally for the text field:

```
  <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-xs-12'>
          {props.selectedReason.reasonId === 2 &&
            <TextField
              required={props.selectedReason.reasonId === 2}
              multiline
              className='text-area'
              fullWidth
              value={props.selectedReason.reason}
              onChange={event => {
                props.handleChangeReason({
                  ...props.selectedReason,
                  reason: event.target.value
                });
              }}
            />
          }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      required: true
    }
    this.makeRequired = this.makeRequired.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }
  makeRequired(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      required: !prevState.required
    }));
  }
  submitForm(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
        <input required={this.state.required} type="text" name="code" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.makeRequired}>
        Make {this.state.required && 'Not' } Required
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this to a function.

```
_text = () => {
  if (props.selectedReason.reasonId === 2) {
    return (
      <TextField
        required
        multiline
        className='text-area'
        fullWidth
        value={props.selectedReason.reason}
        onChange={event => {
          props.handleChangeReason({
            ...props.selectedReason,
            reason: event.target.value
          });
        }}
      />
    )
  }

  return null
}


<div className='row'>
    <div className='col-xs-12'>
      {this._text()}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write this using an if statement or any shorter way?

If you want a slightly clearer way, you can do

```
const content = props.selectedReason.reasonId === 2 ? 
  <TextField ... /> :
  null;

return (
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-xs-12'>{content}</div>
  </div>
);
```

or if you really want to use an `if` statement:

```
let content = null;
if (props.selectedReason.reasonId === 2) {
  content = <TextField ... /> :
}

return (
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-xs-12'>{content}</div>
  </div>
);
```